# Android paypal automatically donate to charity

Tags: java, android, paypal, automation

I could not find any directions or samples for sending automatic paypal payments to charities. Does anyone know how I might go about that. I was thinking they could login once through a trusted paypal login page and then from then on it would send automatic payments to charities until the user changes the settings of course.

Comment: https://www.paypal.com/us/webapps/mpp/get-started/create-recurring-donation-button

Comment: unfortunately I don't think this will work, I need it to be on android and send money automatically based on an event inside the app.